# What is the best way to use maven offline without sync with remote repo?

Tags: java, maven

I am working in a company network which blocks connectivity to remote maven repo,What is the best way to use maven offline without sync with remote repo ?
Do we have option without setting up a mirror in local machine.

Comment: You can add dependency to repository manually, but it is wrong way, so better setup local mirror at some server allow it access to network and use it.

Comment: Yes - just install, for example, [Nexus](https://www.sonatype.com/nexus-repository-sonatype); ideally on server used by all devs. You can then either allow Nexus out to mirror locally or manually upload all required dependencies (caveat emptor: that will be very painful). You're going to need a local Maven repository either way because you need to upload _your_ libraries somewhere!

Comment: Try to build your project using **mvn build** first time it will sync with remote repo for resolving dependencies & you can further build multiple times without doing a **mvn clean** so that a remote sync is not essential except that your dependencies are changed.

Comment: Thanks for the answers,I looked for an answer without creating mirror.So I will try this @shanbhagsv

Comment: You may offer a solution to your company similar to http://gokhanettin.github.io/writing/2018/06/03/bare-minimum-software-development-infrastructure-in-air-gap

Comment: @EmreSülün Good one!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not ideal, but you could build the project outside your company network (at home), then take a copy of your .m2 directory back to your work computer. This works in a pinch and only until you need more dependencies.